# CSS height:0 and overflow:hidden with margin has a different behavior on safari

Tags: css, cross-browser

The problem I have is that I have a div with `margin:20px;` to keep it hidden  i append styles `height:0px;overflow:hidden` to the div. This works well until Safari where the `margin` is not being applied.

Sample code found here https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/1no9u54t/2/

Safari output:

[image]

Other browsers results:

[image]

The difference is in the green outline. On safari, setting `height:0;overflow:hidden;` affects the margin. On other browsers the margin of the div is still in effect.

---

Browsers tested:

- Safari Version 9.0.2
- Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)
- Firefox 45.0.1
- Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0

---

Not really a concern but testing on IE11 produced some interesting results

IE 11 Version 11.0.10240.16431

[image]

Comment: what is that? `outline`?

Comment: yes, i added `outline` to demonstrate the issue

Comment: why not remove the outline like `outline:none` instead of `height:0.01px`?

Comment: its not the outline that i'm concerned about but the difference is spacing from  `margin` property, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work around this was to instead of setting the `height:0px`, replace it with a small value such as `height:0.01px` and it produces a uniform results across the browsers i used test. But I hope someone has a better solution.